# Unrecognized X.509 certificate format error in SSO settings page

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, openam

I tried to configure SSO using OpenAM in salesforce.I have done the following steps.

- Configured the Circle of trust
- Configured the identity provider
- Configured the Salesforce as the service provider
- and download the identity provider certificate in OpenAM
  I received the following error in Salesforce SSO settings page while saving set-up page

**Unrecognized X.509 certificate format error in SSO settings page**

Please help me to successfully configure SSO using OpenAM in salesforce.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

If you export the certificate on OpenAM side, you may check if the boundaries 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' ... 'END CERTIFICATE' are on a separate line

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.It was very useful.Error has been cleared.